# Format a tabulator.js cell based on another value

Tags: tabulator

I would like to color the cell value (Amount) in green only if the value of (KP) is true by maintaining the original money formatting.
This is my actual definition of my 2 relevant columns:

```
{ title: "Amount", field: "amount", width: 60, sorter: "number", hozAlign: "right", headerSort: false, formatter: "money", formatterParams: {thousand: " ", precision: 0 }, bottomCalc: "sum", bottomCalcFormatter: "money", bottomCalcFormatterParams: {thousand: " ", precision: 0}},
{ title: "KP", field: "cache", width: 25, hozAlign: "center", formatter: "tickCross",
headerSort: false, headerFilter: true, headerFilterParams: { tristate: true } },
```

The example shown on the webpage obviously does not work for me as I need to refer to another cell and I want to keep the predefined formatter and formatterParams options

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom function in the formatter, this example from the documentation.

```
   {title:"Name", field:"name", formatter:function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){
        //cell - the cell component
        //formatterParams - parameters set for the column
        //onRendered - function to call when the formatter has been rendered

        return "Mr" + cell.getValue(); //return the contents of the cell
 }
```

It wouldn't be difficult to emulate the money formatter return value, this would be the best approach in my view. Alternatively if you wanted to run a second formatter function following the inbuilt tabulator "money" formatter you could do this by setting the cell element style, something like cell.style.fillColor = rgb etc has worked for me before. I find the first approach far better however.

Refer the documentation here [Tabulator Formatters](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/format#format)

Comment: At the end of the day I've found a solution for this by using a table level rowFormatter function. It is not as nice and clear as applying a style to the cell, but it works. I've used this: row.getCell("amount").getElement().style.color = "#2AD04E". Personally I don't like such amount of concatenation (as it was complicated to find out), but it works and it maintains the original money formatters